# Select2 Search Detect if user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm working with select2 4.0.3 and I can't seem to detect keyup events. What is the right way to go about this?

My code:

Thanks!

```
$('.qty-select').select2({
        tags: true,
    }).change( function(e) {
        checkAmount(e);     
    }).on('select2:open', function (e) {
        checkAmount(e);
    }).on('select2:closing', function(e) {
        checkAmount(e);
        //alert($(".select2-search__field").val());
    }).on('select2:select',function(e) {
        alert('sdfsf');
    });

    $('.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log('User is typing');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // other code here

    $('.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log('User is typing');
    });
});
```

Comment: Then it should work. There's nothing extraordinary going on in what you've posted so the issue must be somewhere else in your code. It's not here in what you've posted.

Comment: I found it in the library, they disable it from working.